# jQuery: AJAX отправка данных на сервер со знаком "%"

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({type:"POST",
        url:'ajax.index.php?option=com_landing&task=products',
        data:({ action:"ajaxSaveData", id:id, idInput:idInput, name:name, value:value, activity:activity }),
        dataType:"json", cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            myThis.next().attr('src','components/com_landing/images/img/'+data.img);
            myThis.next().fadeOut(2500, function(){$(this).remove()});
        }
    });
```

всё прекрасно работает! Но если передавать знак % в текст, то ответ сервера всегда 500 ошибка!
прошу помощи!
надо передавать на сервер текст со знаком процентов!

Comment: Проблема на стороне сервера. Посмотрите в `error_log` там должно быть указано что за ошибка

Comment: Потому, что такие символы представляются в Unicode, и в запросе к серверу символ % играет совсем другую роль. Например, в запросе к поисковику символ $ интерпретируется как %24, а %  - как %25

Answer (score 1):

Какой текст вы имеете ввиду

> если передавать знак % в текст

Если адрес, то необходимо кодировать передаваемую в адрес строку через encodeURIComponent()